# Is an in-feed extension for a table saw useful?

Tags: table-saw

I'm designing a table saw extension for my DeWalt DW745. I've searched for plans and most of them add an out-feed extension to the table saw.

I'd like to cut some dadoes and rabbets in wide boards (>40cm), but set at 2cm high (just a random small height), my table saw only has about 17cm of clearance between the blade and the beginning of the table, so it gets kind of clumsy.

Also, I'd like to use a crosscut sled with said wide boards, but I'm not sure something so big would work without an in-feed extension.

I'm aware that adding in-feed extension would make it difficult for me to access the controls of the machine.

So, would just adding a side extension help me with these problems? Why is it so uncommon to have in-feed extension, at least I haven't seen a single plan which uses it.

Comment: An `adjustable roller stand` ([like this](https://www.harborfreight.com/132-lbs-capacity-roller-stand-68898.html) - the first result in a Google search) might be a better option for the infeed side.

Comment: @FreeMan I hadn't thought of that and I like it, but I'm not sure, would it work with a crosscut sled?

Comment: There are some with bearings on top that will allow material to roll in any direction. You could use one or more oriented parallel to the blade to support a sled. [This one](https://www.amazon.com/Rockler-Ball-Bearing-Stand/dp/B001DT5L8I) is the first result in a Google search for `adjustable ball bearing roller stand`, as an example. If you had, say, 4 of them, you could make 2 parallel rows to support the sled. Based on comments, it looks like each one supports 14", so you'd have a 28" "infeed table".

Comment: *"Why is it so uncommon to have in feed extension"* I suspect it's because at this end you have the most control over the wood to begin with, it interferes with access to the controls (a *major* safety issue) and that it would nearly force the user to lean in steeply over the top of the saw which is something to minimise even on saws fitted with safety guards. But I'm not a table-saw user so what do I know? ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this isn't quite what you asked about it does provide additional support on the in-feed side which is the heart of what you're seeking so perhaps it will do what you want:

[image: Table saw fence extension]

This is an old tip supplied by a reader or contributor to Fine Woodworking that I came across while reading last night and I immediately thought of this Question. Taunton have gotten great mileage out of it having published it at least four times so I presume they think it's good!

The original tip is available as a free PDF download, [Tablesaw fence extension supports a full sheet of plywood](https://www.finewoodworking.com/FWNPDFfree/tablesaw-fence-extension.pdf).

**Safety note**
Just to emphasise something in case it's needed, you *must* build and mount anything like this accurately to ensure it's safe to use. If it's out of parallel with the blade it could lead to binding which is hazardous, at the very least risking damage to the workpiece and at worst serious injury to the operator.

Comment: An aluminium extrusion would serve very well for this design, being perfectly straight with parallel sides. Alternatively, a simple plywood torsion box can also substitute for the fence extension, if a straight and parallel piece of wood cannot be found or manufactured (typically requiring pretty precise tool use)

Answer (score 2):

I have a saw like yours. I don't have an in feed extension, but when cutting wide sheet goods I often use an extension on the fence. I clamp an old four foot level to the face of the fence (any thing long and straight with parrallel sides would work). The level extends about a foot past the fence on the in feed side. This let's me register a lot more of the material against the fence and eliminates any horizontal play. Then I just have to worry about keeping the material level. 
I've thought about putting some kind of lip on the extension to support the material, but I haven't really needed it yet.

Comment: I want to use a big crosscut sled, which is why I thought maybe an in feed extension could be useful. For cutting big sheets I use a track saw.